# About "Frames as Repository of Local State"

Tags: functional-programming, closures, scheme, state, sicp

SICP, Exercise 3.10 in [section 3.2.3](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-21.html#%25_sec_3.2.3) shows the following as an alternative to a previously defined `make-withdraw`:

```lisp
(define (make-withdraw initial-amount)
  (let ((balance initial-amount))
    (lambda (amount)
      (if (>= balance amount)
          (begin (set! balance (- balance amount))
                 balance)
          "Insufficient funds"))))
```

and prescribes that we

> Use the environment model to analyze this alternate version of `make-withdraw`, drawing figures like the ones above to illustrate the interactions
>
> ```lisp
> (define W1 (make-withdraw 100))
> (W1 50)
> (define W2 (make-withdraw 100))
> ```

However, before the above request, the text recalls that `(let ((<var> <exp>)) <body>)` is syntactic sugar for `((lambda (<var>) <body>) <exp>)`.

Now I guess that suggestion means that I should analize actually *this* version of `make-withdraw`:

```lisp
(define (make-withdraw initial-amount)
  ((lambda (balance)
     (lambda (amount)
       (if (>= balance amount)
         (begin (set! balance (- balance amount))
                balance)
         "Insufficient funds")))
   initial-amount))
```

or, even better (based on *The procedure definition syntax is just syntactic sugar for an underlying implicit `lambda` expression*, from [section 3.2.1](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-21.html#%25_sec_3.2.1)):

```lisp
(define make-withdraw
  (lambda (initial-amount)
    ((lambda (balance)
       (lambda (amount)
         (if (>= balance amount)
           (begin (set! balance (- balance amount))
                  balance)
           "Insufficient funds")))
     initial-amount)))
```

And here I see 3 lambda procedures, whereas in both [this](https://github.com/qiao/sicp-solutions/blob/master/chapter3/3.10.png) and [this](https://adrianstoll.com/sicp/3.10.txt) solutions (unofficial; I don't know of official solutions) only two procedures are shown. For instance, this is the latter solution:

```lisp
; After (define W1 (make-withdraw 100))
 global env
------------------
|                |<--- env: global env
|                |     parameters: initial-amount
| make-withdraw: ----> body:
|                |       ((lambda (balance)
|                |          (lambda (amount)
|                |            (if (>= balance amount)
|                |                (begin (set! balance (- balance amount))
|                |                       balance)
|                |                "Insufficient funds"))) initial-amount)
|                |
|                |       E1
|                |     -----------------------
|                |<----| initial-amount: 100 |
|                |     -----------------------
|                |          /\
|                |       E2 |
|                |     ----------------
|                |     | balance: 100 |
|                |     ----------------
|                |          /\
|                |          |
|                |     env: E2
|                |     parameters: amount
| W1: ---------------> body:
|                |       (if (>= balance amount)
|                |           (begin (set! balance (- balance amount))
|                |                  balance)
|                |           "Insufficient funds")
------------------
```

whereas I would have imagined that a procedure with `parameters: balance` and `body: (lambda (amount) …)` was drawn as well, as that's the (temporary?) lambda that's run in `E2` (with `balance` bound to `initial-amount`, not to `100`, which is in turn bound to `100` in `E1`) to generate the procedure that's ultimately bound to `W1`.

Am I correct? If not, can you explain why?

Answer (score 0):

When `(make-withdraw 100)` is called it constructs an environment with `initial-amount` bound to `100` (this is `E1` in the diagram).  It then *immediately calls another function in this environment*: that function constructs a child environment in which `balance` is bound to `100`, which is `E2` in the diagram, and returns a third function defined in that environment, which is thus the return value of `make-withdraw`.

So `W1` is now bound to that third function, whose environment is `E2`.  The second function, which constructed `E2`, has been called and has returned its value (the third function): it's no longer in the picture.

That's why it's not there any more.

---

I'm not sure if it helps, but it might be useful to think of the environment picture if `make-withdraw` didn't exist at all as its really just spurious noise at the point `W1` has been defined (obviously not in real life, where you might want to make several accounts!):

```
(define W1 ((λ (initial-amount)
              ;; this function was `make-withdraw`
              ((λ (balance)
                 ;; this function was `let`
                 (λ (amount)
                   ;; this is what W1 will end up being
                   (if (>= balance amount)
                       (begin
                         (set! balance (- balance amount))
                         balance)
                       "Insufficient funds")))
               initial-amount))
            100))
```